# Add integer value in columns

Tags: c

I have to add integer value to rows.

1. I have to find the String using strstr function
2. From string_1 (COORDINATES) to string_2(END_COORDINATES) i have add the integer value to the rows.
3. give me some suggestion how to perform this operation.

#### Example input file

```
COORDINATES  
5   10   20   30  
5   10   20   30  
5   10   20   30  
5   10   20   30  
5   10   20   30  
5   10   20   30  
5   10   20   30  
5   10   20   30  
END_COORDINATES  
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50
```

#### Example output file

```
COORDINATES  
5   110   220   330  
5   110   220   330  
5   110   220   330  
5   110   220   330  
5   110   220   330  
5   110   220   330  
5   110   220   330  
5   110   220   330  
END_COORDINATES  
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50   
3   30   40   50
```

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <math.h>    

FILE *file_input;
FILE *file_output;

#define COORDINATES     "COORDINATES"
#define END_COORDINATES "END_COORDINATES"

int main(){
    char line[256];
    int SI_no, X_cord, Y_cord, Z_cord;

    int change_in_X_cord, change_in_Y_cord, change_in_Z_cord;
    int user_X_input, user_Y_input, user_Z_input;

    user_X_input = 100;
    user_Y_input = 200;
    user_Z_input = 300;

    ///change in cordinates
    change_in_X_cord = X_cord + user_X_input;
    change_in_Y_cord = Y_cord + user_Y_input;
    change_in_Z_cord = Z_cord + user_Z_input;

    /// File input
    file_input  = fopen("File_output.domm", "r");
    if (file_input == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("%s \n " COORDINATES);

    /// File output
    file_output = fopen("File_output2.domm", "w");
    if (file_output == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%s \n " END_COORDINATES);

    while(fgets(line, sizeof(line),file_input)) {
        if (!strstr(line, COORDINATES)){
            continue;
        }

        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line,file_input)) {
            return 3;
        }

        // pls give me suggestion how to perform this operation
        /*
        while(fscanf(file_input,"%d %d %d %d", &SI_no, &X_cord, &Y_cord, &Z_cord )) {
            if (strstr(line, END_COORDINATES)){
                return 0;
            }
            printf("%d %d %d %d \n", X_cord, Y_cord, Z_cord );
            printf("%d %d %d %d", change_in_X_cord, change_in_Y_cord, change_in_Z_cord );
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your actual question? I'm not sure what the numbers in your data represent, or what value you're supposed to add. And I can't tell from your description what specific step you're having trouble with.

Comment: @Caleb i have add integer values from 2nd to 4th column. for example, 2nd column i have to add 100, then 3rd column 200 and 3rd column 300.

Comment: And what's stopping you from doing that? You seem to have all the tools you need (addition, `fscanf()`, looping), so what problem beyond "show me how to do it" are you having?

Comment: @Caleb i have written this code, but while performing the operation its does't read the input file and print the the output as per requirement

Comment: A very good question to ask yourself when debugging code like this is "what does it do?"  Obviously it doesn't do what you intended, or you wouldn't be debugging it, but what does it actually do?  Can you add more print statements to figure out what it's doing?  Debugging skills like that will pay off in *spades* over the years, trust me.  Sometimes I swear all I do is add print statements to my code to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Which is it? Are you sure it doesn't read the input file? How do you know? If that's really the case, you should post code that illustrates that problem and ask why. StackOverflow is a question and answer site, not a code writing service. Ask a *clear* question and you'll generally get a good answer.

Comment: *"i have add the integer value to the rows"* Really? It looks like you are multiplying the values in columns 2, 3 & 4 by `11` between the tags and leaving the remainder unchanged. If you must use `strstr`, then read each line and ask `char *p; if ((p = strstr (line, "COORDINATES"))) { if (p == line) { /* start mod of rows */ } else { /* end mod of rows */ }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, it is *"How do I use `strstr` to identify the line containing `"COORDINATES"`, then do something with the lines after that line until I reach the line containing `"END_COORDINATES"`, leaving the remainder of lines unchanged."*

Start where you always start when you need to figure out a function `man strstr` (or if you don't have the *man pages* installed [**strstr(3) - Linux man page**](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr). What parameters does it take? **What does it return?** ("*a pointer to the beginning of the substring, or NULL if the substring is not found*")

In order to use the **return** for comparison purposes in your code, you better save it, e.g.

```
...
while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) {
    char *p = buf;
    /* does buf contain "COORDINATES"? */
    if ((p = strstr (buf, "COORDINATES"))) {
    ...
```

So you have read each line and found `"COORDINATES"`. How do you test if the `buf` begins with `"COORDINATES"` given the return from `strstr` saved in `p`?

Where will `p` point if `buf` begins with `"COORDINATES"`? (recall the return: *"a pointer to the beginning of the substring"*) If both `buf` and `p` point to `"COORDINATES"`, then you have found the line `"COORDINATES"`.

If `buf` contains `"COORDINATES"`, but does not begin with it (e.g. `p != buf`), then you have found `"END_COORDINATES"`.

How do you know if you have already found `"COORDINATES"`, but not yet encountered `"END_COORDINATES"`? The easiest way is to simply set a flag like `int coords = 1` when you encounter `"COORDINATES"` and set it to `0` at `"END_COORDINATES"`. Then all you need to do is check `if (coords) { /* do stuff to rows */ }`. Example:

```
    int coords = 0;     /* flag indicating between tags */
    ...
    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p = buf;
        /* does buf contain "COORDINATES"? */
        if ((p = strstr (buf, "COORDINATES"))) {
            if (p == buf) { /* does buf begin with it? */
                printf ("start mod of rows.\n");
                coords = 1;  /* set flag */
            }
            else {  /* contains, but doesn't begin with */
                printf ("end mod of rows.\n");
                coords = 0;  /* unset flag */
            }
        }
        else if (coords) /* flag set, modify rows */
            printf ("modify: %s", buf);
    }
    ...
```

Putting the pieces together in an example showing how to use `strstr` to identify the rows to modify (the rest is up to you), you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 512

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXC] = "";
    int coords = 0;     /* flag indicating between tags */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p = buf;
        /* does buf contain "COORDINATES"? */
        if ((p = strstr (buf, "COORDINATES"))) {
            if (p == buf) { /* does buf begin with it? */
                printf ("start mod of rows.\n");
                coords = 1;  /* set flag */
            }
            else {  /* contains, but doesn't begin with */
                printf ("end mod of rows.\n");
                coords = 0;  /* unset flag */
            }
        }
        else if (coords) /* flag set, modify rows */
            printf ("modify: %s", buf);
    }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/coords dat/coords.txt
start mod of rows.
modify: 5   10   20   30
modify: 5   10   20   30
modify: 5   10   20   30
modify: 5   10   20   30
modify: 5   10   20   30
modify: 5   10   20   30
modify: 5   10   20   30
modify: 5   10   20   30
end mod of rows.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have additional questions.